# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n})^\alpha (2+n^4)^\beta$ convergence/divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to analyze the convergence/divergence of:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n})^\alpha (2+n^4)^\beta$
depending on $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This is how far I have gone:
First i have changed it a bit using $(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ and i have studied this: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2+n^4)^\beta}{((n+1)^{2/3} + (n(n+1))^{1/3} + n^{2/3})^\alpha}$ . I used the limit-convergence test 
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(2+n^4)^\beta}{n^\lambda((n+1)^{2/3} + (n(n+1))^{1/3} + n^{2/3})^\alpha}=l$ and now I would have to chose $\lambda$ so that $0\lt l \lt \infty$. My problem comes now. If i choose $\lambda= 4\beta-\frac{2}{3}\alpha$ the limit shoud be finite and bigger than $0$. So now, would it be correct to say that if $-1 \gt 4\beta-\frac{2}{3}\alpha$ the series is convergent? If it is not correct, how should the problem be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Clayton $a=\sqrt[3]{n+1}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler using *equivalents*

- $\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n}=\sqrt[3]{n}\Bigl(\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac 1n}-1\Bigr)=\sqrt[3]{n}\dfrac1{3n}=\dfrac1{3n^{\tfrac23}}$, so
  $$\bigl(\sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n}\bigr)^\alpha\sim_{\infty}\dfrac1{3^\alpha\,n^{\tfrac{2\alpha}3}}.$$
- $(2+n^4)^\beta \sim_\infty n^{4\beta}.$
  Therefore,
  $$\bigl(\sqrt[3]{n+1} - \sqrt[3]{n}\bigr)^\alpha (2+n^4)^\beta\sim_\infty \dfrac1{3^\alpha\,n^{\tfrac{2\alpha}3-4\beta}}$$
  and the latter, which is a $p$-series, converges if and only if $\;\dfrac{2\alpha}3-4\beta>1$.